# Why does apache2 server take upto 1.5 hours to write a 6 mb .sql file

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server

I have a script which reads a text file with 3mb of data and write a .sql file to import.

this text file is being uploaded to the application from a third party every 1 hour though out the day.

the problem is this script finishes less than 1 min in my local pc. but when the script is running on the production server (which is dedicated serer with 4GB ram, 2 Core processor) takes up to 1.5 **hours**. this scrip used to run under 5 mins in the same environment.

the text files are ziped into a .gz files so I use `gzopen` to oepn the file and `fgets` loop through the file and creates a sql string to to write into a .sql file (following is the string created out of the text file)

```
'INSERT INTO `table` (`col_1`,`col_2`,`col_3`,`col_4`,`col_5`,`col_6`,`col_7`,`col_8`,`col_9`,`col_10`,`col_11`,`col_12`,`col_13`,`col_14`,`col_15`,`col_16`) 
VALUES 
("'.implode('","',
  array(
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$trackNo),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[1]),
     $dateReceived,
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[2]),
     $dateDelevered,
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[3]),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[4]),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[5]),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[7]),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[8]),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[9]),
     date(DATE_ISO8601,time()),
     date(DATE_ISO8601,time()),
     'system',
     mysqli_real_escape_string($this->ds,$ln[4]),
     'txt.gz'))
.'");'
```

this string will be written into a .sql file line by line until the end of `fgets` using `fwrite`

I don't understand why does this process take such long time since on my pc it complete under 2 mins

Comment: Log time at different steps in some log file or console to know which step is taking the bulk of time, the read, implode, write or something else

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I will do that and come with results.

Comment: Looking at the problem objectively you could do some [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Backing up your database would be faster then. It may also be a good idea to look into incremental/partial backup solutions.

Comment: It may have nothing to do with the code itself. Has there been any software update on the server lately? For instance a new version of anti-virus software? That might cause those kind of problems too.

Comment: found the issue, likewise @LoekBergman says is was nothing to do with the script. We have changed a column into a UNIQUE from KEY this lead in to the problem while inserting data into the table. reversed it and now the script runs under 15 sec. thanks for the help cheers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the default `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1`; =2 will run significantly faster because it won't be flushing after each INSERT.

Another approach is to 'batch' the INSERTs.  Building `INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ...` will run up to 10 times as fast.  I recommend batches of 100 to 1000.

1GB of RAM is tiny by today's standards.  I hope you don't have `innodb_buffer_pool_size` bigger than 100M.  Too big a buffer_pool could lead to swapping, which would be really bad for performance.

Comment: found the issue, there was an issue with the schema. one column has changed in to a UNIQUE KEY which was previously a KEY so that to the extra time to validation. anyway thanks for pointing out these changes that I can use to speed up my script I will implement these changes. I was wrong about the RAM the server has 4 GB of ram. thanks for your answer I really appreciate it :-)

Comment: 1500M is probably reasonable for the buffer_pool in a 4GB machine.